# Fixing 'qodbc3:unable to execute statement' when querying SQL Server 2008?

Tags: qgis, sql-server

While testing features of QGIS I tried to query each table using right click and query but I can't query sql server 2008 database :

```
Error:
An error occured when executing the query.
The data provider said:
[microsoft][odbc sql server driver][sql server] invalid object name 'table_test'
qodbc3:unable to execute statement
```

but it works fine with postgis.

Also, is there any why to join table and do the query?

[image]

Comment: the error hints that there is no table named SITES_2G , so wrong database or wrong schema would be my best guess or odbc driver is case sensitive (that depends how driver escapes table names

Answer (score 1):

you need to define ODBC connection from Admintools -> "Data sources" use name as provider/DNS , then tell QGIS to use it.
Also dont enable "only look in the geometry_columns table"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a geometry_columns table in the database in order to connect. Nathan has some more details on [this post](http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/opening-ms-sql-server-2008-spatial-tables-in-qgis-correctly/)

Comment: I have already connected to database but it's problem while I query the database